# How to add multiple gradient color in multiple views in a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

I use the code below for gradient color. But when I use that code it colors the whole view controller. It also covers the other contents too  like textfield, label, etc. I want to use multiple views with multiple gradient colors in a view controller. Suppose I have three views in a view controller and I want to use three different gradient colors in three different views. Content like label and textfield will appear on the gradient colors.

Here is my code:

```
func setBackground_view() {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 44/255.0, green: 156/255.0, blue: 56/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 155/255.0, green: 180/255.0, blue: 23/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

    gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing in your example is applying the gradient to `self.view` which is essentially the root view of the whole `ViewController`. Not only that, but you're also applying the same gradient onto the `self.view` **multiple** times.

What you want is to apply gradients to each element individually, not the `self.view` itself.

Suppose you've got a `UITextfield`, then just apply the gradient as you already did, but instead, apply it directly onto the desired object.

```
textField.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
anyOtherView.layer.insertSublayer(differentGradient, at: 0)
```

And so on and so forth.

**Note:**
Remember to apply the different gradients to their appropriate views, otherwise all the gradients will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the sublayer 3 times with

```
self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Just do

```
func setBackground_view() {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 44/255.0, green: 156/255.0, blue: 56/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 155/255.0, green: 180/255.0, blue: 23/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

    gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

Basically you want to have the `gradientLayer` below all other views that are added in the view controller, that is why you insert it as the bottom most layer by inserting it at index 0.